# are there limited putextra for intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a long text in app and want share this text with whatsapp i use a put extra string to share this text

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mytext);
```

this code good work for short text but for long text share like this :

```
────────────────
─██████████████─
─██░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██████──██████─
────────────────
──────────────────
─██████████████───
─██░░░░░░░░░░██───
─██░░██████░░██───
─██░░██──██░░██───
─██░░██████░░████─
─██░░░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░████████░░██─
─██░░██────██░░██─
─██░░████████░░██─
─██░░░░░░░░░░░░██─
─████████████████─
──────────────────
────────────────
─██████████████─
─██░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██░░██──██░░██─
─██████──██████─
────────────────
──────────────────
─██████████████───
─██░░░░░░░░░░██───
─██░░██████░░██───
─██░░██──██░░██───
─██░░██████░░████─
─██░░░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░████████░░██─
─██░░██────██░░██─
─██░░████████░░██─
─██░░░░░░░░░░░░██─
─████████████████─
──────────────────
────────────────
─██████████████─
─██░░░░░░░░░░██─
─██░░██████░░██─
��
```

this finish text by �� but if copy text from app to whatsapp , text complate copy to whatsapp. this problem is putextra ? or whats app share limited ?